# Why when everything in xUnitTest shows equal but test fails?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, xunit

I want to write a test for this method :

```
public static class JobHelper
{
    public static object ExtractMetaData(string entity, string message)
    {
        return new { entity, message };
    }
}
```

And here is my xUnit Test:

```
public class JobHelperTest
{

    [Theory]
    [InlineData("Name","BMW")]
    [InlineData("Model","2021")]
    [InlineData("Color","Black")]
    public void ExtractMetaDataTest(string entity,string message)
    {

        object expectedValue = new { entity, message };

        object result = JobHelper.ExtractMetaData(entity, message);

        Assert.Equal(expectedValue,result);
    }

}
```

everything looks equal but here is the error message of the test resut:

[image]

Comment: Are `JobHelper` and `JobHelperTest` in different assemblies?

Comment: What do you mean in different assemblies ?

Comment: In different projects? Are associated with different .csprojs? Live in different dlls?

Comment: **JobHelper** is in software.POS.Shared and **JobHelperTest** is in software.POS.Shared.Test, they're both in same solution.

Comment: Right, but in different projects. You can't pass anonymous objects between different projects (you're not even supposed to pass them between different methods, which is why it's not possible to define a method which returns an anonymous type). Change your `ExtractMetaData` function to return an actual class which you define, rather than an anonymous type

Comment: (The reason is that, when you create a new anonymous object, the compiler has to generate a type an embed it in your project. In your example, that type is called `<>f__AnonymousType0`2`). However, it has to do this individually for each project, so each project will have its own version of an anonymous type with the string properties `entity` and `message`. Two such objects from different projects are therefore different, incompatible objects which just happen to look similar)